# how to create a program that reads the data from the text file and prints it out in two different sections

Tags: python

I need a program that groups "names" and "birthdates" from a file and then prints them into two different sections as follows:

Name
A Masinga
Etc.
Birthdate
21 July 1988
Etc.

The names should only be the first letter of the name and then display the surname.

here is my code:

```py
name = []
birthdate = []

#open the file
f = open("DOB.txt", "r+")

for line in f:
    parts = line.split()
    name.append(parts[:2])
    birthdate.append(parts[2:])
    
print("Name")
for i, name in enumerate(name):
    print("{}.{}".format(i," ".join(name)))

print("Birthdate")
for i, birthdate in enumerate(birthdate):
    print("{}.{}".format(i," ".join(birthdate)))
```

Comment: You need to make an attempt and post the code you tried so that others can help you. Please read [How do I ask homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions#:~:text=Asking%20about%20homework,results%20to%20a%20single%20site.)

Comment: @AliasCartellano I keep trying to post the code but I keep getting an error message saying that my code is not formatted properly. So I really don't know what to do ey.

Comment: Did you look at [how to format my questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) Post a smaller portion of your code if it isn't working.

Comment: @AliasCartellano I just added my code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a space between the first name and the surname, you can do this for a list of names called `names`:

```
for i, name in enumerate(names):
    s_idx = name.find(' ')
    print(f'{i} - {name[0]}. {name[s_idx+1:]}')
```

Which, for the first element named `'Leon Johnson'`, would output:

```
0 - L. Johnson
```

Comment: Another thing is that the program is not supposed to be numbered. But I do not how go about it.

Comment: How do you mean 'numbered'? If you don't need the index part (i.e. "0 -" before the initial) you can simply delete `{i} -` from the print line

Comment: I tried running your above code and it doesn't work. It gives me an error that says "list object has no attribute find"

Comment: Sorry, I wrote `name` for both elements of the loop. Retry it now, using `names` as your list

Comment: I keep getting the same error message